# Why is the energy operator special?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Only the energy operator controls the time dependence of a quantum system, but not the others, why is that?

Comment: By *definition* of energy.

Answer (score 2):

The way I like to understand this is in terms of generators of translation. A well known result from classical mechanics (see Goldstein) is that momentum is a generator of translation in the canonical coordinate conjugate to that momentum. For example, linear momentum generates space translations, and angular momentum generates rotations. In Hamiltonian mechanics it is possible to treat time as a true coordinate instead of a parameter, and when this is done, it turns out that the Hamiltonian is the momentum conjugate to time! Thus, energy, or more generally the Hamiltonian, is the generator of time translations which gives the time dependence.

Comment: What do you mean by "Treat time as a true parameter"? Do you mean that you would augment the phase space by two additional coordinate (which then would be hamiltonian and time? If yes, do you know any sources where this treatment is done? I only know Goldstein slightly puts his finges on this subject somewhere in his book, but it's not carried out that far...